# i'm having trouble turning 1 html file in 1 html 1 css and 1 js can some one give me a hand?

Tags: javascript, html, css

so i've started coding but i guess i'm dumb becuase i havan't been able to split this code i'd apreciate some help

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Exploring HTML</title>
<style>
body {
color: red;
}
h1 {
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 32px;
color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My first web page</h1>
<p>This is my first web page, it's a little basic, but it's helping me understand how HTML works and how to markup my content.</p>
<button id="color">Change color!</button>
<script src="js.js">

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: go to this site http://www.w3schools.com/ .. read everything

Comment: not really sure what youre asking

Comment: @gerdi uh no. w3fools is overly promoted, but quite garbage. OP can find everything related to this question there, on  Stack Overflow.

Comment: um.. yeah ok , if you say so. I always did figure the best way to learn programming was to endless scroll through questions

Comment: @nicael - Um, W3Schools is a nice site for beginners, with easy-to-understand sentences and concepts ([said by Paul Irish himself](https://github.com/paulirish/w3fools/issues/50#issue-13645375)).

Comment: Rolled back asshatte's edit; don't edit code in questions!

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can split up your webpage into different files. You want to use `link` in the head tag to include external CSS files. For external `script` files you still use the `<script>` tag but you don't insert any content to it, you apply the `src` attribute. `<script>` tags can be either in the head or the `body` tag, usually it's better to add it to the end of the `body` tag to prevent render blocking.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Exploring HTML</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
   <!-- Body Content -->
   <div id="color">Click Here to Rotate Colors</div>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
body {
   color: red;
}
h1 {
   font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 32px;
   color: black;
}
```

**script.js**

```
(function() {
   // Set the variable "node" and set the event listener on click
   var node = document.getElementById('color');
   node.addEventListener('click',changeColor,false);

   function changeColor(e) {
      // Get the target (node) that the user clicked
      var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

      // Get the color from the data-color attribute
      var color = target.getAttribute('data-color');

      // Define the colors to rotate
      var colors = ['red','green','blue'];

      // Get the position of the color. red = 0, green = 1, etc
      var index = colors.indexOf(color);

      // If the index is the last item in the array you want
      // to change the index to 0 otherwise it increases by 1
      var next = (index+1 == colors.length ? 0 : index+1);

      // Set the new color and the data-color attribute
      target.style.color = colors[next];
      target.setAttribute('data-color',colors[next]);   
   }
})();
```

A working example of the above code can be found at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6t2xv3xg/). The reason I'm setting `data-color` instead of reading the `style.color` variable is because I'm unsure if some browsers may modify this value in different ways. I know for a fact that the browser will not modify the `data-color` attribute.

Comment: this was as far as i got but the function does not change the text color as it's suposed to

Comment: What text color isn't changing? You never asked about having to change text color, only how to split up the files.

Comment: but the file i send has a function that changes the body from red to green

Comment: In the code you provided, there is nothing that changes the color from Red to Green. Maybe you forgot to include some code in your question.

Comment: true stroy its on the js

Comment: // JavaScript source code

document.getElementById('color').onclick = changeColor;
var currentColor = "red";

function changeColor() {
    if (currentColor == "red") {
        document.body.style.color = "green";
        currentColor = "green";
    } else {
        document.body.style.color = "red";
        currentColor = "red";
    }
    return currentColor;
}

Comment: made a new question with all the codding thank you for all the help